# Regex : Capture a string and ignore a certain pattern

Tags: regex

Here's the line which I'm struggling with to exclude a certain pattern (|2 Normal):

```
    #TR|1 Normal    Rationale|2 Normal  Yesterday I ate an apple.|2 Normal  Today, I have some work.|2 Normal   Tomorrow, I'm gonna eat Libanese food.
```

I tried the following expression :

```
    \|\d+ [^\t]+\tRationale([^\|2 Normal]+)
```

From what I know, the sequence ([^\|2 Normal]+) is supposed to write any character that isn't matching with "^\|2 Normal", but it actually doesn't return anything.

**Expected result:**

I want to have this as output:

*"Yesterday I ate an apple. Today, I have some work. Tomorrow, I'm gonna eat Libanese food"*

Or even if possible, to add a line break between each sentence:

*"Yesterday I ate an apple."*

*"Today, I have some work."*

*"Tomorrow, I'm gonna eat Libanese food."*

**Actual results:**

If I enter this regex :

```
   \|\d+ [^\t]+\tRationale([^\|2 Normal]+)
```

This regex above doesn't return anyting
And this one:

```
    \|\d+ [^\t]+\tRationale(.*)
```

Returns :

```
    |2 Normal   Yesterday I ate an apple.|2 Normal  Today, I have some work.|2 Normal   Tomorrow, I'm gonna eat Libanese food.
```

Any solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is is use an alternation to match an optional Rationale or #TR and in the replacement use a newline:

```
(?:\s*(?:Rationale|#TR)?\|\d+ Normal\s+)+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\s*(?:Rationale|#TR)?` - Match 0+ whitespace chars and either Rationale or #TR
  - `\|\d+ Normal\s+` - Match a `|`, 1+ digits (or replace by number 2 exactly), a space and Normal followed by 1+ times a whitespace char
- `)+` - Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E4cuPu/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
In your regex demo link, the thing is I want the information to appear in the "Match Information" area. Which isn't the case with your regular expression. Is it possible?

Comment: @Irchad Do you use a programming language? Now what you don't want is selected and replaced with a newline. You could also use match what you don't want and capture in a group what you do want https://regex101.com/r/Xq0efK/2 or you could skip and fail if pcre for example https://regex101.com/r/Xq0efK/1

Comment: No I'm not using a programming language, actually I'm using a software to allow us to retrieve data using regular expressions.
This expression "(?:\s*(?:Rationale|#TR)?\|\d+ Normal\s+)+|([a-zA-Z0-9 .,'-]+)" worked quite well but in several matches, I guess that is not possible to get "Yesterday I ate an apple. Today, I have some work. Tomorrow, I'm gonna eat Libanese food." in one match and without the break line necessarily

Comment: @Irchad Do you perhaps know what type of regex engine that software uses?

Comment: In the documentation, they say the software uses _Perl Regular Expressions_

Comment: @Irchad Then you might try this regex `(?:\s*(?:Rationale|#TR)?\|\d+ Normal\s+)+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[a-zA-Z .,']+`  See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xq0efK/1)